# How to calculate the sub-differential of the $\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^{2/3})$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, svd

Given a matrix $X\in \Bbb{R}^{m\times n}$, and its singular value decomposition is
\begin{align}
X = U \Sigma V^T
\end{align}
where  $U\in \Bbb{R}^{m\times r}$, $\Sigma\in \Bbb{R}^{r\times r}$ and $V\in \Bbb{R}^{n\times r}$.

My question is how to calculate the following sub-differential:
$$\frac{\partial \operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^{2/3})}{\partial X}.$$

I want to use the gradient-based method to solve an optimization problem with $\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^{2/3})$. Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: Do you really mean $\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^{2/3})$ or did you instead mean $\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma)^{2/3}$ ?

Comment: Yes, I mean $tr(\Sigma^{2/3})$.

Comment: Without some sort of constraint, the problem has a trivial minimum at $X=0.\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$For ease of typing, rename $\,\Sigma\to S\,$
so that
$$\eqalign{
X &= USV^T \quad\iff\quad S = U^TXV \\
}$$
Start by finding the differential of the function with respect to $S,\,$
then change the independent variable from $S\to X,\,$
and finally recover the gradient with respect to $X$.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \trace{S^{2/3}} \\
d\phi &= \tfrac 23\,S^{-1/3}:dS \\
  &= \tfrac 23\,S^{-1/3}:U^TdX\,V \\
  &= \tfrac 23\,US^{-1/3}V^T:dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X} &= \tfrac 23\,US^{-1/3}V^T \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product, which is a convenient notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{AB^T} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a Frobenius to be rearranged in many different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
&A:B = B:A = B^T:A^T \\
&A:BC = B^TA:C = AC^T:B \\
}$$
Since you plan on using this in a gradient-based method, you'll need to update $X$ and recompute its SVD at every step of the iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!